# Assertion failed: (SourceMgr && "SourceManager not set!") with oclint-json-compilation-database

Tags: ios, oclint

I am trying to generate OCLint report.

When I try executing the command "oclint-json-compilation-database --debug" I get the following error :-

Compiling /Users/tavant/Desktop/TestJenkinsCI/TestJenkinsCI/AppDelegate.m**Assertion failed: (SourceMgr && "SourceManager not set!"), function getSourceManager, file /Users/lqi/.jenkins/workspace/oclint-ci/oclint-build-nodes/master/oclint/llvm/tools/clang/include/clang/Basic/Diagnostic.h, line 384.**

I am using oclint 0.9 (the latest version).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with you. I change to the 0.8 stable version, then everything be ok.